# Multiple JSliderNews Sliders

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

Did anyone got the chance to get multiple JSliderNews instances working on one page?
I'm using different selectors for the two sliders - still the behaviour is:

Both sliders are rendering fine, no JavaScript errors, everything seems fine.
But using the navigation items only will move the slides on the second slider. Using the navigation on the second slider will only move the second slider - so first slider is dead, except it controls the second one.

I can't figure out why I can't have two instances of the same plugin on one page...

JQuery plugin: http://www.landofcoder.com/demo/jquery/lofslidernews/

I'm using JQuery 1.7.0

Comment: Please share your `javascript` block of code you used to initialize the both sliders